# How to filter dataframe with multiple boolean conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to filter a pandas dataframe with two boolean queries, means I want to keep the ones which are `True`

dataframe:

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

single filter works:

```
filter = (df.b == 2) 
df = df[filter]
```

output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
```

But how can I filter with `df.b == 2` or `df.b == 5` ?

I tried:

```
filter = [(df['b']==2) | (df['b']==5)]
df = df[filter]
print(df)
```

I get :

```
ValueError: Item wrong length 1 instead of 3
```

Any suggestions how do achive it?
my desired output is:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

Comment: Just do: `filter = (df['b']==2) | (df['b']==5)`

Comment: Do not use filter as a variable as you are overwriting the built-in `filter` function

Comment: also `filter = df['b'].isin((2,5))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass `list` as filter, try this: *(better don't use `filter` as variable, it is [`built-in function`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) in python)*

```
mask = ((df['b']==2) | (df['b']==5))
df = df[mask]
```

You can use `.inin()` as alternative solution like below:

```
mask = [2,5]
df = df[df['b'].isin(mask)]
```